# ieee754 optimization

Tags: c, optimization, ieee-754

Is function `__ieee754_pow()` can be optimized by using `-O` options or `ffast-math`.
Is call for `pow` will be change to call for `cbrt`, if we use nex code:

```
double test (double x)
{
  return __ieee754_pow(x, 2./3.);
}
```

And if the answer is NO, please explain why.

Comment: Depends on the compiler. With `-ffast-math` you explicitly give it a lot of leeway to rewrite floating point computations, so it might. On the other hand, you explicitly asked for the `__ieee754_pow`, so probably it won't. My gcc uses `cbrt` if I call `pow`, but not for `__ieee754_pow`.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes my compiler uses `cbrt` if i call `pow`, too. But if i call `__ieee754_pow` it's still there, im interested why.

Comment: Because you explicitly asked for the IEEE754 version of `pow`, and `double y = cbrt(x); return y*y;` produces different results for some inputs. The compiler honours this request, as I would expect. If you are okay with results that are off by a few ULPs, you shouldn't call functions with names that imply you want IEEE754 behaviour.

Comment: These functions are implemented in the CRT .lib you link.  They are already compiled, optimization options you use in your own code cannot affect the code in that .lib

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar Could you explain how this much-repeated quote relates to the question at hand? The question is about what happens when a call to `__ieee754_pow()` is compiled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler has no way of knowing the semantics of `__ieee754_pow`, i.e. no way of knowing that what it's doing it the "pow" operation. This is because the name `__ieee754_pow` is not specified anywhere; it's an internal implementation detail of your system's math library. In any case, you should not be using it at all, and really shouldn't even be aware that it exists unless you're debugging `libm`, so I don't understand the purpose of this question.

Comment: Don't shoot the messenger. 7.1.3: "All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use." and "If the program declares or defines an identifier in a context in which it is reserved (other than as allowed by 7.1.4), or defines a reserved identifier as a macro name, the behavior is undefined."